# differences between privileged mode and unprivileged mode in the RTX RTOS

Tags: cortex-m3, rtos

As i said in the title what's differences between privileged mode and unprivileged mode in the RTX RTOS?
And why in privileged mode  threads has allowed full access to the cortex M processor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [RTX Documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTX/html/_thread_config.html#ProcessorMode)

> **Processor Mode for Thread Execution**
>
> CMSIS-RTOS RTX allows to execute threads in unprivileged or privileged processor mode. The processor mode is controlled with the **#define OS_RUNPRIV**.
>
> In unprivileged processor mode, the software:
>
> - has limited access to the MSR and MRS instructions, and cannot use the CPS instruction.
> - cannot access the system timer, NVIC, or system control block.
> - might have restricted access to memory or peripherals.
>
> In privileged processor mode the software can use all the instructions and has access to all resources.
>
> **Note**
> It is recommended to use the privileged processor mode.

Privileged and Unprivileged mode is really a feature of the ARM core and RTX is simply making that feature available.  If your application has a reason to restrict privileges for threads than you might choose unprivileged mode.  But I suspect most applications use privileged mode and allow all threads full privilege.

Comment: Is it possible some high important threads use privileged mode and the others use unprivileged ?

Comment: there are 2 definition for MSR and MRS,which one do you mean? 1-Move to system coprocessor register from ARM register.       2-Load an immediate value, or the contents of a general-purpose register, into specified fields of a Program Status Register (PSR). MRS has 2 definition too!